# Where To Find bb_profile_data(); In bbPress?

Tags: database, profiles, bbpress

I posted this same question on WP Forum, but it's completely dead.

So, there is a great tutorial in this blog about showing post count in bbPress at this link.

According to that article, to show post count in bbPress, I should replace

`<?php bb_profile_data(); ?`>

with the following code

```
<?php bb_profile_data(); ?>
<div id="user-stats">
 <?php
 global $bb_table_prefix;
 $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$bb_table_prefix."posts WHERE poster_id = $user_id AND post_status = 0";
 $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$bb_table_prefix."posts WHERE poster_id = $user_id AND post_status = 0 AND post_position = 1";
 echo "Forum Posts: <b>".$bbdb->get_var($query1)."</b> &nbsp; ";
 echo " Topics Started: <b>".$bbdb->get_var($query2)."</b>"; ?>
</div>
```

But I've only one question. Where in the world is that bb_profile_data(); tag. Please help me, it's very important for me...Thanks you guys!!

Comment: Your links are missing.

Comment: If you're on a UNIX-like OS, and have shell access, try this from the bbPress root directory:  `find . -exec grep -iHn bb_profile_data {} \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [reference](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/bbpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html) you get the following info:

```
Function and Method Cross Reference

bb_profile_data()

Defined at:
/bb-includes/functions.bb-template.php -> line 2405
Referenced 1 times:
/bb-templates/kakumei/profile.php -> line 30
```

so you should check your profile template.

If you have ssh access to your site, try

```
# grep "bb_profile_data" -R /the/path/to/your/site/
```

in the shell command line, to search for the `bb_profile_data` string in all the files within the `/the/path/to/your/site/` directory.

### Update:

In bbPress 2.3.2 you seems to have instead:

```
 <p class="bbp-user-forum-role"><?php  printf( __( 'Forum Role: %s',      'bbpress' ), bbp_get_user_display_role()    ); ?></p>
 <p class="bbp-user-topic-count"><?php printf( __( 'Topics Started: %s',  'bbpress' ), bbp_get_user_topic_count_raw() ); ?></p>
 <p class="bbp-user-reply-count"><?php printf( __( 'Replies Created: %s', 'bbpress' ), bbp_get_user_reply_count_raw() ); ?></p>
```

in the file `/plugins/bbpress/templates/default/bbpress/user-profile.php` to display the topics and replies count. You can view the source [here](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/bbpress/tags/2.3.2/templates/default/bbpress/user-profile.php#L24).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm using bbPress 3.2 and there is no /bb-includes/functions.bb-template.php path in my bbPress.